# navbar is getting cutted off when i resize the window

Tags: css, header

When I enter my website and resize the browser to make it smaller and then scroll horizontally to the right, half of the nav bar is getting cut off, I want the nav bar to show all my links even if I have to scroll to the right.

Why is this happening?

here is my css:

```css
#header{
 width:100%;
}

.head{
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 1350px;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color:#303030;
}

nav{
 width:655px;
 margin-top:20px;
 float:right;
 border:2px solid yellow;
}
```

```js
$(function(){
 var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
      if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
   $('.head').addClass('shrink');
   $('#logo').hide();
   $('#postLogo').addClass('now').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.head').removeClass('shrink');
   $('#logo').show();
   $('#postLogo').addClass('now').hide();
        }
  });
  function getCurrentScroll() {
  return window.pageYOffset;
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please

Comment: when i use min-width it only affects the below the header, why?